# How do "Galois-type" and "saturation" for AECs generalize "type" and "saturation" in first-order model theory?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, definitions

As I'm not allowed to ask a new question due to limit reached matter,
I still want to **EDIT** this one as communicated with @Alex Kruckman
in the comments below. I would like to understand the **relationship** of the two
definitions relating AEC's notion of a **type** by assuming existence
of **amalgamation** in Jarden's approach with realizing formulas in elementary extensions in Hodge's approach. What should I take for an AEC $(K,\preceq)$
to obtain exactly Hodge's notion and prove its equivalence with the amalgamation
approach ?

**OLD Question:**

I have come across two different definitions of saturation and I would like to relate them.
One is in Wilfrid Hodges book (first snippet below) and it says that an elementary extension $B$
realizes all types with less than $<\lambda$ elements. The other approach is the definition 1.0.25 in the second snippet below.
It says that $M$ of cardinality $\lambda^+$ is saturated if $M$ realizes type of every sub-model of cardinality $\lambda$. I do not even know what is to be proved for an equivalence of these two
approaches. It appears to me that in the second approach we are looking at **smaller** models and in the first approach at **larger** elementary extensions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Voting to close as not research level - but while I'm here: your summaries of what these definitions say are all wrong. The Hodges definition doesn't say all types with less than $\lambda$ elements are realized, it says that all types *over sets $X$ with $|X|<\lambda$* are realized. The Jarden-Shelah definition doesn't say all types *of* submodels of cardinality $\lambda$ are realized, it says all types *over* submodels $N$ with $|N|=\lambda$ are realized.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I understand what you write, but still Hodges uses **formulas** while Jarden **amalgamation**; how can I relate these two concepts ? What should I take for $(K,\preceq)$ in Jarden's approach ?

Comment: Well, that's a totally different question. It's because the Hodges definition is in the context of model theory of first-order logic, while the Jarden-Shelah definition is in the context of AECs, where there is no such thing as a formula. As for why the notion of Galois type in AECs is a suitable replacement for the notion of type in first-order logic, this deserves its own question.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I will definitely write one with the hope that you will not downvote this time.

Comment: Indeed, I will not downvote if your question is of good quality (e.g. not including images of text from books or links to the middle of long PDFs).

Comment: @AlexKruckman I was not allowed to ask a **new** question, hence I needed to **EDIT** my actual one. Though to avoid retyping all the stuff I kept the 2 images in it.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for up-voting. I just tried to press the button `Ask question` but the limit not permitting to ask a new question persists. Do you happen to know why or what action from others can clear it ? Or shall I just wait ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I've done an EDIT but the ban from asking a new question still persists...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the mechanics of restrictions on the site very well. Maybe it's related to the fact that your [Math Stackexchange account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/122424/user122424) is temporarily suspended? Anyway, I hope my answer helps. I'm going to take the liberty of editing your title to make it match the question more clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the context of abstract elementary classes (AECs) is a generalization of the context of model theory of first-order logic. For any first-order theory $T$, we can let $K$ be the class of models of $T$, and let $\preceq$ be the elementary substructure relation between models of $T$. Then $(K,\preceq)$ is an AEC. [Thus the name: $(K,\preceq)$ is an elementary class, and the axioms of AECs are intended to abstract the properties of elementary classes].

For the rest of the answer, let's fix the first-order theory $T$, and the corresponding elementary class $(K,\preceq)$ as above.

Next, I'll explain how the notion of Galois type from AECs is a generalization of  the notion of type (over a model) from model theory. Let $M\models T$. Let's write $S(M)$ for the set of first-order complete types over $M$ and $gS(M)$ for the set of Galois types over $M$ in $(K,\preceq)$. We'd like to establish a bijection between $S(M)$ and $gS(M)$. Let $p\in gS(M)$. Then $p$ is the $E_{K,\preceq}$ equivalence class of some triple $(M,N,a)$ where $M\preceq N$ and $a$ is a tuple from $N$. We map $p$ to $\text{tp}_N(a/M)\in S(M)$, the complete first-order type of $a$ over $M$ in the model $N$.

- To check the map is well-defined, it suffices to show that if $(M,N,a)E^*_{K,\preceq}(M',N',a')$, then $\text{tp}_N(a/M) = \text{tp}_{N'}(a'/M')$, since the equivalence relation $E_{K,\preceq}$ is the transitive closure of $E^*_{K,\preceq}$. By definition, if $(M,N,a)E^*_{K,\preceq}(M',N',a')$, then $M = M'$ and there exists $N''$ with $N'\preceq N''$ and an elementary embedding $f\colon N\to N''$ which fixes $M$ pointwise and has $f(a) = a'$. But then $$\text{tp}_{N}(a/M) = \text{tp}_{N''}(f(a)/M) = \text{tp}_{N'}(a'/M').$$
- The fact that the map is injective is a consequence of a standard amalgamation result in model theory (see Theorem 6.4.1 in Hodges). If $\text{tp}_N(a/M) = \text{tp}_{N'}(a'/M)$, then there is an elementary extension $N'\preceq N''$ and an elementary embedding $f\colon N\to N''$  which fixes $M$ pointwise and has $f(a) = a'$. This exactly says that $(M,N,a)E^*_{K,\leq} (M,N',a')$, so the $E_{K,\leq}$-equivalence classes of $(M,N,a)$ and $(M,N',a')$ are equal.
- The map is surjective, because for any complete first-order type $q(x)\in S(M)$, $q(x)$ is realized by some tuple $a$ in some elementary extension $M\preceq N$. Then $q(x)$ is the image of the equivalence class of the triple $(M,N,a)$.

Ok, so when we're working with an elementary class, a Galois type over a model $M$ is essentially the same thing as a complete first-order type over $M$.

Finally, we want to see that the notion of saturation as defined by Jarden-Shelah is a generalization of the notion of saturation in model theory. In your quoted passage, Jarden-Shelah define what it means for $M$ to be "saturated in $\lambda^+$ over $\lambda$". I claim that when we're working with an elementary class, $M$ is saturated in $\lambda^+$ over $\lambda$ if and only if $M$ has cardinality $\lambda^+$ and is saturated (i.e. $\lambda^+$-saturated).

One direction is trivial: If $M$ has cardinality $\lambda^+$ and is $\lambda^+$-saturated, then for any model $N\preceq M$  with $|N| = \lambda$, every complete $n$-type over $N$ is realized in $M$ by saturation (i.e. $M$ is full over $N$), so $M$ is saturated in $\lambda^+$ over $\lambda$.

In the other direction, suppose $M$ is saturated in $\lambda^+$ over $\lambda$. Let $X\subseteq M$ with $|X| <\lambda^+$, and let $p(x)\in S(X)$ be a complete type over $X$. By Löwenheim-Skolem, we can pick an elementary substructure $N\preceq M$ with $X\subseteq N$ and $|N| = \lambda$. Let $p'(x)\in S(N)$ be any extension of $p(x)$ to a complete type over $N$. Since $M$ realizes every type in $S(N)$, $p'(x)$ is realized in $M$, and hence so is $p(x)$. So $M$ is $\lambda^+$-saturated.